# Static analyser to detect two post/pre increment operators

Tags: c, compilation, static-analysis

I have a huge code base. It has statement as shown below:

```
int a = ( (unsigned int) ((unsigned char) buffer[offset++]) << 8) | (unsigned int) (unsigned char) buffer[++offset];
```

Recently I migrated to higher version of a compiler. With compiler migration, evolution of complex statements as shown above resulted in inconsistent results.

I know this is a bad coding practice and want to correct it. Looking for static analyser which can flag these errors. Any pointers to perticular static analyser is appreciated.

Comment: clang detects with `-Wunsequenced`, gcc with `-Wsequence-point`

Comment: It is not just bad practice, it is an undefined behavior bug. Tool recommendation questions are off-topic, but _any_ half-decent static analyser will scream at this code. If you want to be sure, pick one which can check for compliance with MISRA-C (most of them can, nowadays). Mixing ++ with other operations in the same expression is banned by MISRA-C, which would have prevented this bug.

Comment: Also, it is clear by these casts that whoever wrote this code had absolutely no idea about how implicit type promotions work in C. This too would be solved by reading MISRA-C, which has a strong focus on how to avoid implicit type promotion bugs.

Answer (score 4):

It's not just bad coding practice.

**It's dreadful. You are introducing an absolute truck load of undefined behaviour into your program.**

`|`, unlike `||`, is **not** a *sequencing point*. You are increasing `offset` twice, conceptually at the same time. The C standard does not define this behaviour.

You need to fix this immediately. Shelve the static analyser for now. Your compiler warning flag suite might be able to help you. But if I were in your position, I'd be in panic mode and I'd search my code base for `++` and `--`, and check every expression.

Comment: Compilers are not required to warn for undefined behavior, so getting a static analyser would still be a good idea.

Comment: Well yeah, pretty much all static analysers on the market are broken in some way... but they are still better than just compiler warnings, or no analyser at all.